# How to create const and variables in Resource.designer.cs?

Tags: variables, xamarin

Why do I need write this code:

```
 public const int myButton = 2131034112;
```

What is the other way to create the button (and other variables)?

Comment: You need to create an .xml layout file. The `Resource` class will generate automatically from the IDs you use in the .xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm the vote up I just made for Daniel, if you want to Add resources that you can access via Resource.Id.{ControlName} or Resource.Layout.{LayoutName or View Name}, you need to add layout files to your project. Those Layout files will contain the controls for what appears in your app and you'll be able to use the LayoutInflater to create views from them.

I will say this, sometimes in Xamarin studio.. you'll need to close the Resource.Designer.cs file.. because you'll make changes.. and they won't reflect in that file.. immediately.  Usually when I'm doing Monodroid work.. I get frustrated with how often I have to close and re-open that file to get my controls or layouts working in intellisense.

Comment: If you are looking to make const values.. look under your Resources folder, for the "values" folder.  Inside there you'll see a pile of files that you can effectively "hardcode" app settings into.  Since you didn't vote up Daniel, I had to admit I may not have read the question right.